# How can I estimate a weighted linear regression with fixed effects and many groups in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have a data set derived from administrative registers covering the population of a small European country, containing a large number of defined groups (15 000+). For each of these groups I have multiple observations (different years), and two explanatory variables that characterize the exposure of each group to a policy intervention.

In STATA I would estimate this using the regression command, with aweight=group_size and using absorb(group_identifier). I've done this before, and it is extremely fast. How do I do this in R?  In R, my problem is that I cannot find a package that allows me to both weight by group size AND include fixed effects.

Using the standard lm function I could include the group-size weight, but would have to estimate the group-effects explicitly (simply adding the groups identifier as a factor variable). This is extremely time consuming (I cancelled it after it had run for several minutes).

Alternatively, I could turn to fixed-effects packages - such as the lfe package. These allow for fixed effects, but I have not found any such package that also accepts weighting by group size.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe `glm` could be an option?

Comment: glm has weights, but does it have anythiong similar to STATA's "absorb" that allows me to include fixed effects but repress them in the output?

Comment: hmmmm not completely sure about that, maybe this can help? http://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-models-with-multiple-fixed-effects/

Comment: I found the wfe function in the wfe package, which seems to be exactly the right thing. see documentation:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wfe/wfe.pdf
and code:
https://github.com/cran/wfe/blob/master/R/pwfe.R